# Scala: method parameter type mismatch

Tags: scala, types

Have been programming in Scala for a while and just starting to learn using domain types in Scala. The domain I am trying to model is [time series forecasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forecasting). A simple description is as follows: we have a dataset (e.g., an array of doubles) that we need to fit to a forecasting method, and then we need to use the fitted model to forecast future values. In my case, I am trying to fit multiple methods to the data, and chose the best fitted model (based on some statistic) for forecasting.

On the code front, I have tried to design the domain by lining up the forecasting method type to all the remaining aspects of the domain. So for example, I should not be able to use a fitted model from method A for forecasting from method B. The following code shows a minimal implementation.

In this code, I am trying to pass a typed parameter to a Scala method that takes argument of the same type, and end up getting a cryptic message from the compiler. Here is the code.

```
import scala.collection.mutable

class MethodTypeTest
{
    // A Time Series Forecasting method
    trait TSM[T <: TSM[T]]
    {
        def fit(): FiR[_ <: TSM[_]]
        def fcst(ts: TS, fim: FiM[T]): Seq[Double]
    }

    // A fitted model from a forecasting method
    trait FiM[T <: TSM[_]]
    {
        val fitErrors = mutable.HashMap[String, Double]()
    }

    // A fitted result containing a pointer to the method, 
    // and the fitted model
    case class FiR[T <: TSM[_]](m: T, fiM: FiM[T])

    // A dataset
    class TS
    {
        // Variable to store the best model
        var bestModel: Option[FiM[_ <: TSM[_]]] = None
    }

    // Now define for SMA (a forecasting method)
    // Class for fitted SMA model
    class SMAM extends FiM[SMA]
    {
        fitErrors("RMSE") = 10
    }
    // Class for the SMA method
    class SMA extends TSM[SMA]
    {
        override def fit() = new FiR[SMA](this, new SMAM())
        override def fcst(ts: TS, fim: FiM[SMA]) = Seq(10, 10, 10)
    }
    // Now define for DMA (another forecasting method)
    // Class for fitted DMA model
    class DMAM extends FiM[DMA]
    {
        fitErrors("RMSE") = 10.5
    }
    // Class for the DMA method
    class DMA extends TSM[DMA]
    {
        override def fit() = new FiR[DMA](this, new DMAM())
        override def fcst(ts: TS, fim: FiM[DMA]) = Seq(10, 20, 30)
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    {
        // Set up a new dataset
        val ts = new TS
        // Fit the dataset to methods, to get fitted models back
        val fms = Array[FiR[_ <: TSM[_]]](new SMA().fit(), new DMA().fit())
        // Calculate the best fitted model
        val bestFiR: FiR[_ <: TSM[_]] = fms.minBy(r => r.fiM.fitErrors("RMSE"))
        // Now call fcst() from the bestModel
        // ************* Error ******************
        // type mismatch;
        // found   : MethodTypeTest.this.FiM[_$9]
        // required: MethodTypeTest.this.FiM[_$10]
        //        bestFiR.m.fcst(ts, bestFiR.fiM)
        // **************
        // Popup error says: Required FiM[$1], Found FiM[_ <: TSM[_]]
        bestFiR.m.fcst(ts, bestFiR.fiM)
    }
}
```

The type of `fim` in `fcst()`, as defined in the `TSM` trait seems to conform to the parameter that is passed in the error line. Where am I going wrong here, and how do I fix the issue? I tried changing the definition of `FiR` to `case class FiR[T <: TSM[T]](m: T, fiM: FiM[T])` to tighten the bound (I think!), but that didn't help.

Also, how to read the compiler error of:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : MethodTypeTest.this.FiM[_$9]
 required: MethodTypeTest.this.FiM[_$10]
        bestFiR.m.fcst(ts, bestFiR.fiM)
```

What are those `_$9` and `_$10`?

Comment: Higher kinded types, F-Bound Polymorphism and existential types. This is far for being something to start with.

Comment: Have been coding in Scala for a while - thought I will try out domain driven design in the problem I am working on. Hmm .. seems like it is harder than I thought it would be ... :-(

Comment: The problem is related to existentials which seem to be caused because of the F-Bound although I am on cellphone and is hard to track. Maybe it would be worth to open another question explaining the model you are wanting to model and link to this as an attempt.

Comment: I'm also not really sure that you need HKT/F-Bound/existential types to do domain-driven-design.

Comment: Please try to provide a more minimal or understandable example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez: Thanks for the comments - I probably overthought the solution. I have added a minimal description of what I am trying to do. Please let me know if that helps. Would be happy to add more clarifications - thanks for your comments.

Comment: @francoisr Added more clarification - thanks for your comments.

Comment: @LeviRamsey: Agree with you, that is not required. In fact, I could remove all the type bounds and run it just fine (https://scastie.scala-lang.org/samikrc/Q1nxnjKTT7CJHPmYplZ5qA/5). Still, I guess I am trying to learn if I can use stronger  type-bounds in the domain. Based on the use case in the OP that I have added, do you think there isn't much value to using those type bounds?